# How to get commented cells with SQL QUERY?

Tags: sql, excel

in Excel, there's an option to write comments on your cells. 
I want to get the content of these commented cells (with a SELECT SQL query), but i don't know if this is possible and what should i put in my "WHERE" condition.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is not a database as such and cannot SQL queries on excel objects(Worsheet, Cell, Range....).
 
It has its own DOM (Document Object Model) which can be used to access the objects and their properties and methods. Excel VBA programming will help us here to access these objects and their details.
A simple Excel VBA code to access the comment text is given below:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Comment.Text
End Sub
```

Here Cell A1 has a comment with certain text. This comment text value is captured and stored in Cell A2.
[image]